# Is there any API in Jira to translate the actual values in Jira payload from user's locale to English

Tags: azure, jira, jira-rest-api, payload, language-translation

In Jira, it is possible to change the locale of the user so that the user can see the attributes in their language in UI. When the issue is created/updated by this user and the payload arrives with attributes names or values in any other language than English to Cosmos, it causes the problems with metrics calculations and reporting filtering.

Is there any Jira API or any other solution to translate the names of the fields and the actual values to English.

From my analysis I found out that we can use Azure Cognitive Services Translator Text API, since we have the subscription to it and using other third party translation service is not encouraged.